# Hibernate No Session (No Dependencies)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following JPA entity (generated with Netbeans):

```
package com.tsystems.tf.db.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author johorvat
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Testcase.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Testcase t")
})
public class Testcase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TESTCASE_ID")
    private BigDecimal testcaseId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TESTCASE_NAME")
    private String testcaseName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "CREATOR")
    private String creator;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "CREATED_AT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(name = "LAST_RUN")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastRun;
    @Column(name = "LAST_RUN_RESULT")
    private Character lastRunResult;
    @Column(name = "INPUT")
    private String input;
    @Column(name = "OUTPUT")
    private String output;

    public Testcase() {
    }

    public Testcase(BigDecimal testcaseId) {
        this.testcaseId = testcaseId;
    }

    public Testcase(BigDecimal testcaseId, String testcaseName, String creator, Date createdAt) {
        this.testcaseId = testcaseId;
        this.testcaseName = testcaseName;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTestcaseId() {
        return testcaseId;
    }

    public void setTestcaseId(BigDecimal testcaseId) {
        this.testcaseId = testcaseId;
    }

    public String getTestcaseName() {
        return testcaseName;
    }

    public void setTestcaseName(String testcaseName) {
        this.testcaseName = testcaseName;
    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getLastRun() {
        return lastRun;
    }

    public void setLastRun(Date lastRun) {
        this.lastRun = lastRun;
    }

    public Character getLastRunResult() {
        return lastRunResult;
    }

    public void setLastRunResult(Character lastRunResult) {
        this.lastRunResult = lastRunResult;
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (testcaseId != null ? testcaseId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Testcase)) {
            return false;
        }
        Testcase other = (Testcase) object;
        if ((this.testcaseId == null && other.testcaseId != null) || (this.testcaseId != null && !this.testcaseId.equals(other.testcaseId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.tsystems.tf.db.models.Testcase[ testcaseId=" + testcaseId + " ]";
    }

}
```

I try to implement CRUD operations for this entity using Hibernate but I get LazyEvaluationException. There are NO references. Its only 1 table in the database... I can query but when I try to issue update the exception is being thrown. Now I have a really naive implementation that looks like the following:

```
package com.tsystems.tf.dao.impl;

import com.tsystems.tf.dao.ITestcaseDAO;
import com.tsystems.tf.db.models.Testcase;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.apache.catalina.tribes.util.Arrays;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class TestcaseDAOImpl implements ITestcaseDAO {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration = configuration.configure();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registryBuilder = registryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

        StandardServiceRegistry registry = registryBuilder.build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Testcase> getAllTestcase() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        Collection<Testcase> testcaseCollection = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Testcase.findAll");
            testcaseCollection = query.list();

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (final HibernateException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestcaseDAOImpl.class)
                    .error(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));

            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();
        }

        session.close();

        return testcaseCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public void createTestcase(Testcase testcase) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Testcase readTestcase(BigDecimal id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        Testcase testcase = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            testcase = (Testcase) session.load(Testcase.class, id);

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (final HibernateException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestcaseDAOImpl.class)
                    .error(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));

            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();
        }

        session.close();

        return testcase;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTestcase(Testcase testcase) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.update(testcase);

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (final HibernateException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestcaseDAOImpl.class)
                    .error(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));

            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();
        }

        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteTestcase(BigDecimal testcaseId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

When the update is being called bamm No Session. Why is this happening? GetAll succeeds nice and smooth but that's all to it. Everything else returns in No Session error in my logs.

StackTrace:

```
14-Nov-2014 16:54:43.012 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-148] com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put JSF1063: WARNING! Setting non-serializable attribute value into HttpSession (key: testcaseProvider, value class: com.tsystems.tf.beans.TestcaseProvider).
14-Nov-2014 16:54:46.812 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-148] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{testcaseProvider.updateTestcase()}: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
 javax.faces.FacesException: #{testcaseProvider.updateTestcase()}: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2403)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2392)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.tsystems.tf.db.models.Testcase_$$_jvsta1c_0.setTestcaseName(Testcase_$$_jvsta1c_0.java)
    at com.tsystems.tf.beans.TestcaseProvider.updateTestcase(TestcaseProvider.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more

14-Nov-2014 16:54:46.832 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-148] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2403)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2392)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.tsystems.tf.db.models.Testcase_$$_jvsta1c_0.setTestcaseName(Testcase_$$_jvsta1c_0.java)
    at com.tsystems.tf.beans.TestcaseProvider.updateTestcase(TestcaseProvider.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Why do you mark your method as @Transactional and open/close session in each method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your static block by a before() method, and add the session creation at the end of it :

```
@Before
public void before() {    
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration = configuration.configure();

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    registryBuilder = registryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    StandardServiceRegistry registry = registryBuilder.build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

and an after() method :

```
@After
public void after {
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

And of course, remove all open/close session in each test.

Comment: Although I don'T have these annotation I added two methods: OpenSession and CloseSession which I call in my bean's PostConstruct and PreDestroy methods which solves the problem. Thank you!